# Passing JavaScript Codes via PHP POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I have two textareas, an iframe and a submit button. They are all in the same page. What I want to do is that; user will code some html and javascript codes in to the first textarea. the second one is already hidden to pass the javascript codes. After the user click submit button, s/he will see results in the iframe. actually what i am saying is something like w3school's trying page.

my submit button is:

```
<INPUT type="submit" value="Run the Codes" name="submit" onclick="sendthem()">
```

my textarea's are:

```
<TEXTAREA id="textareaCode1" style="WIDTH:100%;HEIGHT:400px" name="code22" rows="21" wrap="logical" cols="42"><?=$code;?></TEXTAREA> //the user's textarea

<textarea  id="textareaCode"  style="WIDTH:100%;HEIGHT:400px" name="code"  rows="21" wrap="logical" cols="42"><?=$code;?></textarea> //this is actually hidden (style="display:none;") one but to see what happens, temporary i made it visible.
```

and my sendthem() function is:

```
function sendthem()
{
var t=document.getElementById("textareaCode1").value; //the visible textarea
t=t.replace(/</g,"SMALLER"); //string manipulation to pass js codes via php post
t=t.replace(/>/g,"GREATER"); //string manipulation to pass js codes via php post
t=t.replace(/=/g,"EQUAL"); //string manipulation to pass js codes via php post
document.getElementById("textareaCode").value=t; //manipulated code goes in to hidden textarea
document.getElementById("sampleform").submit(); //send the form
}
```

And my php code is:

```
<?
$code = $_POST['code'];
echo "$code"; // here i can see the manipulated code like "SMALLERhtmlGREATER"
?><br/><? // to try it :
$code = str_replace("GREATER", ">", $code); // I reverse the changes
$code = str_replace("EQUAL", "=", $code);
$code = str_replace("SMALLER", "<", $code);
printf("%s",$code); //and there is no js codes.. i tried echo or other php print commands also.
?>
```

Here is a screenshot http://i57.tinypic.com/sghcba.png (I hope it helps)

Now.. I think my problem is in the PHP part. Can anyone tell me why I can't see the JS part of code, after reversing changes ?

And please, I don't want to change all my codes with jQuery or AJAX etc.. I want to fix this code. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You don't need to do all those string replaces. When you post a form, it will be URL-encoded properly, and PHP will decode it automatically.

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't. I am dealing with this problem for 4 days. The PHP POST just can't take the JS codes in any way.

Comment: You need to put the JS codes inside a `<script>` block in the iframe.

Comment: @Barmar but how? and it is not just the JS codes that between `<script>` there is also `onclick=StartWorker()>` part.. After passing it becomes `onclick>`... `=StartWorker()` part is just getting lost.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why the `onclick` is being lost. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Barmar no error in the console. I have asked this question a few days ago also, and ppl said that PHP can't pass any JS codes. So I wanted to do string manipulation just like w3school did. In this link, see the `submitTryit()` function: (view-source): http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_color . They have done, so I want it too..

Comment: Of course PHP can pass JS codes. PHP doesn't care what the code is, it prints anything. And many PHP pages create JS codes.

Comment: @Barmar then what is the problem here? any idea please? :(

Comment: I don't know. I can't think of a reason why it doesn't work. Is your page accessible?

Comment: @barmar here is the link: http://htmldersleri.org/yedek/ornekler/dene.php?dosyaadi=tryhtml5_webworker but it is turkish.

Comment: I get several errors in the Javascript console. `document.getElementById("sampleform").submit();` gets an error because the form doesn't have an ID. And I got 3 errors saying *The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://htmldersleri.org/yedek/ornekler/dene_gor.php' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.*

Comment: @barmar i fixed the 'id' thing of form. but the rest, I don't have any idea what it is talking about.. anyway, thanks a lot...

Comment: @barmar i think problem is google chrome. my page works perfectly on ie and firefox. i just realized that. thanks a lot...

Comment: Another problem. Don't use `name="submit"` for the submit button. When you do that, `document.getElementById("sampleform").submit` refers to the button, so you can't call it as a function to submit the form.